# How can I pass multiple cursors to a single GitHub GraphQL query with multiple node ids?

Tags: graphql, github-api, github-graphql

I'm trying to batch my GraphQL queries to retrieve the data I need from multiple repositories with the same request, where each repository has a different cursor.

Assuming I have the IDs of 3 nodes and only 2 cursors with the following mapping:

```
NODE_ID_1 <-> CURSOR_X
NODE_ID_2 <-> Empty
Node_ID_3 <-> CURSOR_Y
```

How can I populate the GraphQL query so that I can query all 3 nodes, but pass their respective cursors?

```
query {
  nodes(ids: ["NODE_ID_1", "NODE_ID_2", "NODE_ID_3"]) {
    ... on Repository {
      databaseId
      stargazers(first: 100, after:???) {
        pageInfo {
          endCursor
        }
        edges {
          starredAt
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [aliases](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#aliases) by iterating over nodes and map them to a field name like `nodeX` :

```graphql
{
  node1: node(id: "MDEwOlJlcG9zaXRvcnkxMDQ4MzQ4") {
    ... on Repository {
      ...Repo
    }
  }
  node2: node(id: "MDEwOlJlcG9zaXRvcnkyMzE5NDk4") {
    ... on Repository {
      ...Repo
    }
  }
  node3: node(id: "MDEwOlJlcG9zaXRvcnkyMzI1Mjk4") {
    ... on Repository {
      ...Repo
    }
  }
}

fragment Repo on Repository {
  name
}
```

output:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "node1": {
      "name": "DROP5.0"
    },
    "node2": {
      "name": "subsurface"
    },
    "node3": {
      "name": "linux"
    }
  }
}
```

For the cursor value you just need to map the field name to both the node id and the cursor value:

```graphql
{
  node1: node(id: "MDEwOlJlcG9zaXRvcnkyMzE5NDk4") {
    ... on Repository {
      name
      stargazers(first: 1, after:"Y3Vyc29yOnYyOpIAzR1p") {
        pageInfo {
          endCursor
        }
        edges {
          starredAt
        }
      }
    }
  }
  node2: node(id: "MDEwOlJlcG9zaXRvcnkxMDQ4MzQ4") {
    ... on Repository {
      name
      stargazers(first: 1, after: null) {
        pageInfo {
          endCursor
        }
        edges {
          starredAt
        }
      }
    }
  }
  node3: node(id: "MDEwOlJlcG9zaXRvcnkyMzI1Mjk4") {
    ... on Repository {
      name
      stargazers(first: 1, after:"Y3Vyc29yOnYyOpIAzQzi") {
        pageInfo {
          endCursor
        }
        edges {
          starredAt
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In this case your input map would look like:

```js
input = {
    "node1": {
        "id": "MDEwOlJlcG9zaXRvcnkyMzE5NDk4",
        "cursor": "Y3Vyc29yOnYyOpIAzR1p"
    },
    "node2": {
        "id": "MDEwOlJlcG9zaXRvcnkxMDQ4MzQ4",
        "cursor": null
    },
    "node3": {
        "id": "MDEwOlJlcG9zaXRvcnkyMzI1Mjk4",
        "cursor": "Y3Vyc29yOnYyOpIAzQzi"
    }
}
```

With variables:

```graphql
query ($id1: ID!, $cursor1: String, $id2: ID!, $cursor2: String, $id3: ID!, $cursor3: String) {
  node1: node(id: $id1) {
    ... on Repository {
      name
      stargazers(first: 1, after: $cursor1) {
        pageInfo {
          endCursor
        }
        edges {
          starredAt
        }
      }
    }
  }
  node2: node(id: $id2) {
    ... on Repository {
      name
      stargazers(first: 1, after: $cursor2) {
        pageInfo {
          endCursor
        }
        edges {
          starredAt
        }
      }
    }
  }
  node3: node(id: $id3) {
    ... on Repository {
      name
      stargazers(first: 1, after: $cursor3) {
        pageInfo {
          endCursor
        }
        edges {
          starredAt
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

variables :

```json
{
  "id1": "MDEwOlJlcG9zaXRvcnkyMzE5NDk4",
  "cursor1": "Y3Vyc29yOnYyOpIAzR1p",
  "id2": "MDEwOlJlcG9zaXRvcnkxMDQ4MzQ4",
  "cursor2": null,
  "id3": "MDEwOlJlcG9zaXRvcnkyMzI1Mjk4",
  "cursor3": "Y3Vyc29yOnYyOpIAzQzi"
}
```